# How to store session id with request all?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save the passed course_id into lesson form in a DRY format.

I've tried saving each variable individually and it worked, however when I try to DRY up the code it is not working. Here is the code That I've tried.

```
public function store(StoreLessonsRequest $request)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('lesson_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $request = $this->saveFiles($request);
    $lesson = Lesson::create($request->all() +
    $lesson->course_id = session()->get('id') +

        + ['position' => Lesson::where('course_id', $request->course_id)->max('position') + 1]);


    foreach ($request->input('lesson_materials_id', []) as $index => $id) {
        $model          = config('medialibrary.media_model');
        $file           = $model::find($id);
        $file->model_id = $lesson->id;
        $file->save();
    }


    return redirect()->route('admin.exams.create', ['course_id' => $request->course_id]);
}
```

I expected the course_id to save, but is giving me an error of Unsupported operand types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally solved it. First I've declared the variable then I've passed it through.

```
   public function store(StoreLessonsRequest $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('lesson_create')) {
            return abort(401);
        }

        $request = $this->saveFiles($request);
        $seesion = session()->get('id');
        $lesson = Lesson::create($request->all()

            + ['position' => Lesson::where('course_id', $request->course_id)->max('position') + 1] + ['course_id' => $seesion] );


        foreach ($request->input('lesson_materials_id', []) as $index => $id) {
            $model          = config('medialibrary.media_model');
            $file           = $model::find($id);
            $file->model_id = $lesson->id;
            $file->save();
        }
```